# Sum Amount Per Month Between Date Ranges

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table that stores scheduled charges within a date range. I am looking to sum the values per month, but am unsure how to structure the query to handle the range logic. A simplified version of the table structure is below where dates are in MM/DD/YYYY format:

```
Start         End          Amount  
01/15/2020   04/30/2020     200    
02/05/2020   06/30/2020     300   
03/01/2020   12/15/2020     400 
04/02/2020   10/25/2020     500
```

The output would display a sum for every month there are records for based on an entry existing in the Start or End column for that month. So the output would look like this:

```
Month        Amount  
01/2020      200    
02/2020      500   
03/2020      900    
04/2020      1400  
05/2020      1200    
06/2020      1200  
07/2020      900    
08/2020      900  
09/2020      900    
10/2020      900  
11/2020      500    
12/2020      500
```

Any ideas of how to handle this without a separate table storing each month/year to check if it is within the range?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive CTE and then aggregate:

```
with cte as (
      select datefromparts(year(start), month(start), 1) as dte, end, amount
      from t
      union all
      select dateadd(month, 1, dte), end, amount
      from cte
      where eomonth(dte) < eomonth(end)
     )
select dte, sum(amount)
from cte
group by dte;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2abed137d824ee1698469c058db32baf) is a db<>fiddle.